# Swift 2.0: Delegate is not working

Tags: ios, delegates, swift2

I have created the class(customAccessaryView) and extends the `UIView` where I show the Done and Cancel button on `UIToolbar` which I had loaded from `.xib`.

Please find the below screenshot for more information.

[image]

In my customPickerView class I had declared my protocol methods and delegate and I had bind the **doneAction** and **cancelAction** via `.xib`.

**Class : customAccessaryView**

```
@objc protocol customAccessaryDelegate {

  optional func clickONDone()
  optional func clickONCancel()
}

class customAccessaryView : UIView {

 var customView: UIView!
 var delegate:customAccessaryDelegate?    

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.customView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomAccessary", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
    self.addSubview(self.customView)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

  }

  @IBAction func doneAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate.clickONDone?()
    }

    else {

        print("Not Called")
    }
  }

  @IBAction func cancelAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate.clickONCancel?()
    }

    else {            
        print("Not Called")
     }
   }
 }
```

When I will assign the delegate to another class(createEvent) then the protocol method do not call.

**Class : createEvent**

```
class createEvent : UIViewController, customAccessaryDelegate {

  var txtFieldInstance: UITextField!
  var customAV: customAccessaryView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    self.customAV = customAccessaryView()
    self.customAV?.delegate = self
  }

  func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.txtFieldInstance = textField
    textField.inputAccessoryView = self.customAV
    return true
  }

  func clickONDone() {

    self.txtFieldInstance.resignFirstResponder()
  }

  func clickONCancel() {
  }
}
```

As I had used the customAccessaryView for display the inputAccessoryView in keyboard for handling the done and cancel action.

Also I have assigned the delegate and call the desired method but it did not call it.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Update**

When I forcefully declared the delegate in `init` method of `customAccessaryView` class then it is working. Please look into the below code.

```
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

     self.delegate = createEvent()
  }
```

But I did not provide it forcefully.

Comment: What is not working exactly? In `doneAction()`, is printed "Not Called" or is `doneAction()` not even called?

Comment: I have updated the question and actually clickONDone() method in createEvent class not called which is delegate.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This answer is wrong :) I missed the line in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:`.

---

In your view did load you have the lines

```
self.customAV = customAccessaryView()
self.customAV?.delegate = self
```

The first line doesn't do what you're expecting - I assume you want to get the customAccessoryView you created from the storyboard and set it's delegate? What you're actually doing is creating a new CustomAccessoryView and setting it's delegate. You never add it to your view so the instance you're a delegate to isn't the one you can see on your screen.

You need to make your property an outlet

```
@IBOutlet var customAV: customAccessaryView!
```

And attach it in the storyboard to the views you've created in there. Then delete the first line from your viewDidLoad so you're always using the one that's in the storyboard.

---

NB Here's some (probably unwelcome) advice:

Classes in Swift should start with a capital letter i.e. `customAccessaryView` should really be `CustomAccessaryView`. Same goes for protocols. Instances of things start with a lowercase letter so you can easily tell them apart when you're reading through the code.

You've made the delegate method optional, but you then use `!` when you call it. If you're going to do that, why bother making it optional in the protocol? (or if you want it to be optional, use `delegate.clickONDone?()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and guideline regarding creating a class. As you had mentioned that "You never add it to your view", as I have used it in "inputAccessoryView" for displaying so could it consider or not. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hmm, that means my answer is wrong :) The next thing I would look at is whether your delegate is still set correctly in CustomAccessaryView - do you see "Not Called" in your console when you click on the buttons?

Comment: I did not say that your answer is wrong but it does not work for me. Yes I get "Not Called" in console. Please if you have time then please look at it as I am struggling it for last 3 to 4 days and did not know why it is not working.

Comment: I have updated my question please look into it @deanWombourne.

Comment: Can you try removing the `?` from the line `self.customAV?.delegate = self` ? (I'm guessing now, your code looks like it should work!)

Comment: When I removed the `?` then it gives me error like **Value of optional type 'customAccessaryView?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?**